# How to add visualisation for time planning (What Django package to reuse)?

Tags: django

I apologize if if this question is not too concrete and   deserves downvote from developers but I am breaking google for some time already and can't find anything.

I have to add some resource planning to my existing inventory management software.

In our factory I currently manage time of employees by adding them as resource that is required to produce some item.

Let's say I produce Item A and it requires 1unit of Material M1, 2 units of Material M3 and 5 hours of Agent777.

So at any point of time I know what  my agent is currently have assigned to him.
It works and all good but now management  want some resource planning visualisation/tool.

Now we  want to see some visualization similar to microsoft project  on how much each Agent is loaded with orders plotted on weekly timeline.

Is there a package , API, 3rd party app (it is ok if it requires license and have a cost) I can add to my application easily to get the desired?

Ideall will be django package so I would be able to tweak it if required but not limited to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no answers I will answer my own question .
The decision was to try to integrate with some of the existing tools without directly embedding then into our project. First, one we are looking at Trello/taiga-back